# php DataGrid equivalent

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datagrid, crud

i am building CRUD pages for over 20 tables with different schemes 
in ASP .NET i just need to use DataGrid and (almost) everything is handled automatically

is their any equivalent for DataGrid in php that will allow user to add, delete and update records in mysql table with out the need to write all the php/SQL codes

Answer (score 4):

[phpGrid](http://www.phpgrid.com) (www.phpgrid.com) can handle all you CRUD needs. It's a commercial product, but man, it worths every penny. You can also download the free lite version and use it for free.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are some DataGrids which have php libraries to make crud operations. Some of them are not free. You can take a look at this nice list of selection. http://php-team.blogspot.com/2009/05/10-jquery-datagrid-plugins.html

If you want to generate php code, there are free and commercial software, i advice you to take a look at phpmaker.

Answer (score 0):

You can try DaDaBIK www.dadabik.org.
Disclaimer: I'm the author.